# Azure API Management To VNet

Tags: azure, networking, azure-api-management

I am using Microsoft Azure. Specifcially I have API Management Set up as a public gateway. Internally we have a VNet (Its actualy hosting in Azure Environment Service, so its basicallyan isolated App Service inside). I want to connect to the App Service inside the VNet from my API Management service (i.e. route calls from Api Management to backend services in my App Services in the VNet).

I know i can use the network connection to connect as an external API Management to my VNet , but this requires the Premium service level of API Management which is super expensive. Is there a way to route traffic from API management standard Version (which does have a Static IP) through to a service inside a VNet/Subnet though some configuration (other than network connection from the API Management blade).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use API Management in the VNET then you are limited to Premium or Developer.  However, the App Service Environment can have an external interface and API Management can talk to that.

You would need to add some additional security to your external interface to ensure only API Management has access.  This could just be an IP filter rule.

Comment: Thanks Darrel. So you suggest setting the ase as an external and filtering ip access to that?

Comment: @Noel Without knowing more details about your environment, I can't definitively say that is the best solution for your scenario, but it is one way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hey Darrell. Yep I appreciate that. We are setting up some core services as a number of function apps which will be running in a Azure Service Environment v2. So basically inside a vnet. We will also have a gateway down to an on prem net too. The all gateway will be the interface into those functions. I wanted to avoid the premium tier with apim . I am thinking a more traditional approach as you mention (public vnet) to work as a kind of dmz)

Comment: Correction: the apim will be the external interface down to the functions inside the vnet.

Comment: There is an "Under review" discussion for this topic in the "Azure Feedback Forum" not yet resolved (see https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/33997723-support-vnet-for-basic-tier-of-apim)